# Get error for telegram inline keyboard

Tags: php, keyboard, inline, telegram, telegram-bot

I ran into a problem trying to use a telegram inline keyboard when using html tag in url.

```
$var = urlencode("https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=@channel&parse_mode=html&text=\xF0\x9F\x8C\x8D+<b>Hello</b>");
$text = "Hi";
   $keyboard = [
      'inline_keyboard'=>[
       [
           ['text'=>'Click','url'=>$var]
       ]
   ]
];
$keyboard = json_encode($keyboard);
$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?chat_id=MY_ID&parse_mode=html&reply_markup=".$keyboard."&text=".$text;
```

I get BUTTON_URL_INVALID error.
But everything is ok after deleting `<b>Hello</b>`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what's the reason behind this but it seems `html` can not be used as `parse_mode` in this situation.

Try using `Markdown` instead and change `<b>Hello</b>` to `*Hello*`.

So your first line will change to:

`$var = urlencode("https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=@channel&parse_mode=Markdown&text=\xF0\x9F\x8C\x8D+*Hello*");`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It worked. But i really need html. I'm not familiar with Markdown. For example i don't know how to insert new line and non breaking space &#160 ;.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send URL encoded JSON, so just use `"....&reply_markup=" . json_encode($keyboard) . "&text=..."`

You can prove this yourself by `var_dump($keyboard)` and `var_dump("to string: $keyboard")`.

Comment: @Ali Sorry for my mistake, it is `json_encode`, not `urlencode`. Updated to my post :P